# Manifolds which are finite simplicial complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

How can I force a topological manifold $M$ to be homeomorphic to a finite simplicial complex? Obviously $M$ needs to be compact, but this is far from sufficient.

In particular is there any "purely topological" way to do it? (Without introducing more structures on $M$ such as smooth, ect?)

Answer (score 4):

I am translating the question "How can I force a topological manifold $M$ to be..." as "what are sufficient conditions for a topological manifold $M$ to be..."

Classically (i.e. work of Rado and Moise), it is know that every topological manifold of dimension $\le 3$ admits a triangulation (i.e. is homeomorphic to a simplicial complex). In low dimensions, the existence of a triangulation is equivalent to the existence of a PL structure, but this breaks down in higher dimensions. The question of triangulability belongs to the circle  of problems called "Hauptvermutung." You can find some history and references in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptvermutung) Wikipedia page on Hauptvermutung. In particular, if your manifold $M$ has dimension $\ge 5$ and $^4(,{\mathbb Z}/2)=0$, then $M$ admits a PL structure, in particular, a triangulation. Ditto if $M$ is an open 4-manifold. What happens (in the case of closed manifolds) in dimension 4 is anybody's guess, although in the simply-connected case many sufficient conditions follow from Freedman's and  Donaldson's work.